# Why does (()) equal ()?

Tags: python

```
>>> (()) == ()
True
>>> (())
()
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`()` is a 0-tuple. `(foo)` results in the value of `foo`. Hence, `(())` results in a 0-tuple.

From [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> ; a tuple with one item is constructed
>   by following a value with a comma (it
>   is not sufficient to enclose a single
>   value in parentheses).

Answer (score 6):

For the same reason that `(4) == 4`: adding parentheses around an expression does not alter its meaning (unless it would otherwise have been grouped differently of course).

Note that `( foo )` is **not** a 1-tuple. Otherwise things like `3 * (4 + 5)` would be an error as `(4 + 5)` would be a 1-tuple containing 9 and you can't add a number to a 1-tuple.

Answer (score 2):

I see now. From [the tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html).

> ; a tuple with one item is constructed
>   by following a value with a comma (it
>   is not sufficient to enclose a single
>   value in parentheses).

So (()) is not the tuple that contains the empty tuple - this is that tuple: `((),)`

Comment: And under certain conditions the parens aren't even required. `>>> 3,` `(3,)`